# How long does a Bracha last for if I'm moving around in a building?

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating

I work in a school with quite a large building. I have my own office, but I spend a lot of time out of it, checking the building, going into classrooms etc. If I make a Bracha on food and then leave my office for a short while, do I have to make another Bracha when I come back in order to continue eating?

Comment: May I suggest you continue your research with Rabbi Forst's book about brachos until someone else steps up to answer your question ? http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P_2QlQkNL8sC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA188#v=onepage&q&f=false please do not misconstrue this with RTM or google it yourself :) just a busy day over here.

Comment: p.s. the link is to the relevant section of the book

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18741/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio duplicate?

Comment: @msh210 I don't think so.  The other question is about drinks that you refill over the course of the day, while this question is (by my reading) about food that is all present when you make the b'racha but then you leave for a while.  They might have the same answer but they seem like different questions to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have in mind that you will eat all over the building, so long as you don't go 72 consecutive minutes without eating, the bracha is still good. If you did not have this in mind, you cannot go out of sight from the room where you started. i.e. the bracha dies and you have to make a new one when you return to the original room.

There might be a catch to do with eating something you didn't expect to eat.

No sources on me right now. Advice is "as is." If you find yourself in Gehinnom, please contact your local service provider.

Comment: So you are saying if he works at the MetLife building (3.1 million square feet) he is free to roam around all day as long as he stops every 72 minutes ?

Comment: yes. If he had the wandering in mind.

Comment: Why 72 minutes?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think 72 minutes is the standard length for how long a bracha lasts.

Comment: @Scimonster Why would you think that?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because i remember learning it somewhen.

Comment: @scimonster it's not true though