# Make a new leisheiv basucah if you go to a different succah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sukkah, location

If someone is eating in one succah, makes a proper leisheiv basucah, and then gets up and goes into a different succah, do they need to make another bracha?

My question is only about leisheiv basucah, not mezonot. With an ordinary food bracha, you can continue eating in a different location as long as you planned to be there (see [How long does a Bracha last for if I'm moving around in a building?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35049/how-long-does-a-bracha-last-for-if-im-moving-around-in-a-building)).
With leisheiv basucah though, it seems to be tied to the location (it's not said if you're not in a succah, for obvious reasons). That's why i wonder if it might need to be said again in the new location.

Comment: not sure, hoever, if you make a bracha achrona before moving on to the next sukkah and then making a new leshev basukah with what your eating you can avoid this difficulty altogether

Comment: @Dude I doubt that would be effective. Ending my food bracha doesn't end my sukkah bracha. Consider if I want to eat more food in the same sukkah without having left at all (eg. breakfast then lunch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intended to go to that other Sukkah when you made the original Bracha, you can go without making another Bracha there (Mishna Berura 639 sk 48). If you didn't intend to transfer Sukkot when you made the Bracha then if you transferred there would be a Safek about the Bracha and therefore you shouldn't transfer, but if you did anyway you wouldn't make a new Bracha like all cases of Safek regarding Brachot (Shaar HaTziyun ibid. sk 94).

The Arukh HaShulchan (639:28) implies that in all cases a Bracha on one Sukkah wouldn't help for another Sukkah.